# SQL query to select an integer randomly from a given list of integers?

Tags: sql, sql-server, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a list of integers resulting from a `SELECT` query.

The list of integers is not sequential! For example it might contain values like

```
 1,2,3,8,12,17,20,23,28,30,...
```

I want to select one integer **randomly** from that list! How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

based on your statement: "*select one integer **randomly** from that list*", you can use `NEWID()` on this case.

```
SELECT TOP 1 colName
FROM tableName
ORDER BY NEWID()
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/40d47/2)

Other Link(s)

- [NEWID()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190348.aspx)